# How can I set State based on other state in functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I build a simple todo app with a react with an array of todos:

```
const todos = [description: "walk dog", done: false]
```

I use the following two states:

```
  const [alltodos, handleTodos] = useState(todos);
  const [opencount, countOpen] = useState(alltodos.length);
```

This is the function which counts the open todos:

```
  const countTodos = () => {
    const donetodos = alltodos.filter((item) => {
      return !item.done;
    });
    countOpen(donetodos.length);
  };
```

When I try to add a new todo, I also want to update the `opencount` state with the `countTodos` function.

```
  const submitTodo = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const data = {
      description: todo,
      done: false,
    };

    handleTodos([...alltodos, data]);
    console.log(alltodos);
    countTodos();
  };
```

This does not work as expected, the when I run `console.log(alltodos)` it will show an empty array. The function itself works, but it seems to have a "delay", I guess based on the async nature of the `useState` hook.

I tried to pass the `countTodos` function as callback like this, since I have seen something similar in class based components.

```
handleTodos([...alltodos, data], () => {
  countTodos();
});
```

I get the following error:

```
Warning: State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument. To execute a side effect after rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect().
```

How can I solve this problem? What is the best way for me to update the state based on another state?

Comment: callbacks don't work on functional components

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should useEffect, (clearly stated on the log message ). this is an example :

```
useEffect(()=>{
    const donetodos = alltodos.filter((item) => {
      return !item.done;
    });
    countOpen(donetodos.length);
   //countTodos();
},[alltodos]];
```

You can refer to the documentation : https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Here is an example : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-useeffect-forked-4sly8

Comment: great, this works. I´ve been taught that useEffect should only to used for API calls and other side effects, thanks for this snippet!

Comment: You can optimize this by directly calling your function `countTodos` in useEffect.

Comment: @NidhiDadiya: Can you show me how? Would the "alltodos" dependency not block the `countTodos` from executing?

Comment: `useEffect(()=>{ countTodos() },[alltodos]];`